# Ruby error after installing heroku toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku

I am working with Heroku on a win 7 - 32 bit system where I don't have admin privileges.

I have downloaded and installed the heroku toolbelt following http://community.webfaction.com/questions/11803/heroku-toolbelt with

```
cd ~
curl http://assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz | tar zx
export PATH=$HOME/heroku-client/bin/:$PATH
```

following Leo's advice ,I've added ruby to the windows path to fix this

Now when I run:

```
$ heroku run bash --app MYAPP
```

I get:

```
f:/heroku-client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `spawn': Exec format error - "m:/heroku-client/bin/heroku" update (Errno::ENOEXEC)
    from f:/heroku-client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:164:in `background_update!'
    from f:/heroku-client/lib/heroku/updater.rb:144:in `inject_libpath'
from f:/heroku-client/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I have added to the windows env variable path:

```
F:/heroku-client/bin/;f:/heroku-client/lib/heroku/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you run ruby commands? it looks like it can't find the ruby executable.

Comment: I don't know ruby, what command should I enter?

Comment: You could try `ruby -v`?

Comment: I ran that and got : sh.exe": ruby: command not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issues initially with ROR on Windows. (Everyone suggested me to move to LINUX/UNIX)

Still I managed to install it on Windows. Rather than installing the Heroku Toolbet (which breaks ruby and rails which is already installed) install the heroku gem along with foreman gem.

> gem install heroku
>
> gem install foreman

Then u can use it easily.

Comment: That's the best method I've found so far for Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Windows Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows). It's self-contained and should work out of the box for you.

Comment: Hi Jim, I've tried that but it appears you need admin privileges, which I don't have in this setting.