# Git Bash giving sh.exe: ruby: command not found

Tags: ruby, git, bash

I am using Git Bash on Windows Vista Business. I am trying to install Redmine. Basically on step 4, I need to get RubyGem installed before I install the bundler as part of the dependency install (http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall). I downloaded rubygems-2.2.2.zip from https://rubygems.org/pages/download. Then I unzipped the file a folder on my desktop.

In Git Bash, I typed `ruby setup.rb`, I get `sh.exe: ruby: command not found`. Is it something related to the `PATH` environment? If so, how do I include it so that Git Bash will see the setup file and run it?

Ruby 1.9.3- p545 is already installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426805/6309 could help.

Comment: Before you do anything you need to install the Ruby language itself. You didn't say if you had done that or not. If you didn't then you should, and/or edit your question to clarify what you have installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby error after installing heroku toolbelt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770114/ruby-error-after-installing-heroku-toolbelt)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you already installed ruby, you have to include correct path.

Right click `My Computer`, click `Properties`, go to `Advanced System Settings` left navigation, click on `Environment Variables...` button, go to `System Variables` below, select `Path`, click `Edit` and in the beginning of the path enter: `C:\Ruby200\bin;` (Please note that in here you should indicate the ruby executable path. In case you installed ruby using Ruby installer for windows then the above mentioned path is correct).

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me. I installed ruby, my path has `C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;` added to the beginning. I've restarted the shell. Still getting ruby: command not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I got it. Apparently running it from a shortcut holds onto the old PATH variables - until machine restart. Launching git-bash from the start menu worked fine.