# Git Commands not working

Tags: php, git, bash, wamp

I am using the latest version of Git in bash and I am trying to execute basic commands e.g `php`. I have set the environment variable to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` in `Path`.

However when I execute these basic commands nothing comes up, not even `sh.exe:  command not found`. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

[image]

Comment: What does your `PATH` environment variable looks like from inside mingw?. You might want to launch it again after having modify the path from your control panel

Comment: I am not sure what is going on :( i re install wamp and now when i type php in git bash it just sits there and git just hangs thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an environment variable for php. Generally can I say: Gitbash have to know where your command is installed. For php, see below:

- Right click My Computer
- click Properties
- go to Advanced System Settings left navigation
- click on Environment Variables... button
- go to System Variables below
- select Path, click Edit and in the beginning of the path enter: C:\PathToYourPhpDir\bin; (Please note that in here you should indicate the php executable path. In case you installed php via e.g. the Windows installer).

Related question: [Git Bash giving sh.exe: ruby: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713582/git-bash-giving-sh-exe-ruby-command-not-found)